# Including navigation drawer to all activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi I'm trying to include the navigation drawer to all activities in my app. But I'm getting error as the code must contain the id as android.R.id.list. This is my code. What I exactly need is to include the drawer layout to all other activities. I googled a lot and tried with many samples but nothing helped me.

Base Class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, mFrameLayout, true);

    super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);

}
```

drawer layout xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

And my activity to which I need to add the navigation drawer is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_category);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Comment: what is the problem in your navigation drawer . its working in your mainactivity? not working in other activity....

Comment: Yes.. But I have separated the drawer class and including to other activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , it will work , but my navigation drawer class will be in same activity page itself .

```
public class Alerts extends ActionBarActivity 
    implements OnItemClickListener
    {


        //for Navigation Bar
            DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
            ListView listView;
            String[] drawerlist;
            ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

            private MyAdapter4 myAdapter4;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.alerts);



                    //navigation initialize
                            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
                            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
                            drawerlist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerlist);

                            myAdapter4 = new MyAdapter4(this);
                            listView.setAdapter(myAdapter4);

                            //for navigation click

                            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

                            //Navigation Bar starts

                            drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                           (this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                                        R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
                            {

                                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
                                {
                                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                                }

                                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                                {
                                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                                }
                            };

                                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
                                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/
                }

        //for Action Bar Back Button
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) 
                {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    this.finish();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }



                            // Creating the Navigation Bar

                            protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                            {
                                super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                drawerListener.syncState();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
                            {

                                if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
                                {

                                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                                }

                                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.Add:
                                  Intent addIntent = new Intent(this, Add.class);
                                  startActivity(addIntent);
                                  break;
                                case R.id.help:
                                  Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, Help.class);
                                  startActivity(helpIntent);
                                  break;

                          }     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                            }

                            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
                                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
                            }


                            class MyAdapter4 extends BaseAdapter
                            {
                                private Context context;
                                String[] list1;
                                int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_action_image1,
                                        R.drawable.ic_action_image2, 
                                        R.drawable.ic_action_image2,
                                        };      


                                public MyAdapter4(Context context){
                                    this.context = context;
                                    list1 = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerlist);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public int getCount() {

                                    return list1.length;

                                }

                                @Override
                                public Object getItem(int position) {

                                    return list1[position];
                                }

                                @Override
                                public long getItemId(int position) {

                                    return position;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                                {

                                    View row = null;
                                    if(convertView == null){

                                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.easy_nav1, parent, false);


                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        row = convertView;

                                    }

                                    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                    ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                                    titleTextView.setText(list1[position]);
                                    titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

                                    return row;
                                }


                        }
                            // navigation drawer click listener
                            private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener 
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    selectItem(position);
                                }

                            }

                            private void selectItem(int position) {

                                // update the main content by replacing fragments

                               // Fragment fragment = null;
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);

                                switch (position) {
                                case 0:
                                    Intent addIntent1 = new Intent(this, YourActivtyPage1.class);
                                      startActivity(addIntent1);
                                      break;

                                case 1:
                                    Intent addIntent2 = new Intent(this, YourActivtyPage2.class);
                                      startActivity(addIntent2);
                                    break;



                                }   
                            }  

                            }
```

your activivty xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Action Bar -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

// Add your xml what you need

                </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:divider="#bdc3c7"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:entries="@array/drawerlist" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT :1

inside String add your Navigation drawer items
strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="drawerlist">
        <item>navlist1</item>
        <item>navlist2</item>


    </string-array>

    <string name="drawer_open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close Navigation Drawer</string>
```

Comment: try this code it will work for all activities, like this i done in my app